Fourier coefficients for non-periodic signals
Suppose there exists an LTI system h[n]:
$$
h\left[n\right]=\:a^{-|n|}
$$
Let x[n] represent a discrete signal defined as:
$$ x[n] = $$\begin{cases} 
1 & 0 < n < N_0 \\
\text{else} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
Now, let's define the output of the convolution as:
$$ 
y[n] = x[n]*h[n]
$$
Since h[n] is aperiodic, y[n] is also aperiodic and thus does not have a Fourier series representation. However, it is still possible to calculate the Fourier coefficients of y[n]?

Hi: It's possible to calculate the convolution in the time domain. Here's a pretty nice explanation of how to do that ? https://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-convolution/

For your particular question, this example is better than the one above. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIs0h34iFN8

Hi, thanks for answering. I know convolution can be done but I ask about the Fourier coefficients, Can I calculate Fourier coefficients even though the signal y[n] is aperiodic?

so are you saying that you want the fourier coefficients of the series created by the convolution ?  if that's correct, then fourier series representation can only be obtained for periodic series. but I think you can still do DFT or DTFT etc. hopefully someone else will comment because I don't feel comfortable giving advice on this question.
